# Swift: Hide status bar on only one child view controller

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar

I have a problem when it comes to the status bar and hiding it.

## The setup

I have a **BaseViewController** that has a slide out menu. This BaseViewController is also the root controller of the application [as set inside AppDelegate]:

```
window = UIWindow()
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
window?.rootViewController = BaseController()
```

As soon as I select a menu item the BaseViewController is populated by the corresponding ViewController [after I embed it into a navigation controller].

Menu item A: **ViewControllerA**

Menu item B: **ViewControllerB**

Menu item C: **ViewControllerC**

Say that I select the Menu Item A (the following code takes place inside BaseViewController):

```
let activeVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewControllerA())
view.addSubview(activeVC.view)
addChild(activeVC)
```

When I select another menu item (say item B), I first remove the previous active view controller (in this case item A) and then I add the ViewControllerB the same way as I did with ViewControllerA:

This is how I remove the previous active view controller:

```
activeVC.view.removeFromSuperview()
activeVC.removeFromParent()
```

## Manipulating the status bar in each view controller separately:

I set the **View controller-based status bar appearance** to YES in **plist** control the appearance of the status bar in every view controller:

[image]

Then I go into the ViewController I want to hide the status bar and I add the following code:

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
```

## The problem

If I want to hide the status bar inside any of the ViewController A, B, or C, I can't. Overriding the prefersStatusBarHidden and setting it to "true" will do nothing.

If I override the prefersStatusBarHidden and setting it to "true" into the BaseViewController, then the BaseViewController and also any of the ViewController A, B, and C will hide the status bar.

## What I want

I want to be able to hide the status bar on ViewControllerB without hiding it on the rest. Also a million dollars, but I will settle with the solution!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you may need to manually call setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621354-setneedsstatusbarappearanceupdat)

Comment: Please don't show pictures of code. Replace the pictures of code with the actual code, just like you have in other parts of your question.

Comment: @oyvindhauge i did this inside ViewControllerB inside an animation block but it did not help. Maybe i did it wrong. How would you setup this?

Comment: @rmaddy i will fix it as soon as i find myself a laptop :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to override `var childForStatusBarHidden: UIViewController?` for `BaseController` and for `UINavigationController`. For example:

```
override var childForStatusBarHidden: UIViewController? {
    return children.first
}
```

and

```
extension UINavigationController {

    open override var childForStatusBarHidden: UIViewController? {
        return topViewController
    }
}
```

Comment: Your response guided me to the right track and I figured it out. At first, I went into the BaseController and added what you suggested with a twist: I used "return children.last". Then inside the ViewControllerB I set the "prefersStatusBarHidded" to "true". But here is the catch: If your VC is embedded inside a navigation controller, and if you are using a device with no bezels (such as iPhone X) you need to remove the navigation bar for the status bar to be hidden. So I also used navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false). And now it works!

Comment: This is not strictly true. It is not necessary to hide the navigation bar to get the status bar hidden, though doing so likely triggers a status bar refresh. As other commenters have pointed out you can trigger a status bar refresh directly by calling `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate `

Answer (score 0):

I had a use case where I had to present a `ViewController` nested inside a navBar controller the only way which worked for me is adding the following on initilization of a presented ViewController.

```
modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = true
```